# Generating thumbnail from video without an AVAsset on Mac OS

Tags: macos, video, avurlasset, nsfilewrapper

I have a document based app here where I need to generate thumbnails from videos I have available in NSFileWrappers. Problem is that I can't get the file URL from the filewrapper, and I can't seem to create a AVURLAsset without a URL.

Anybody have any suggestions as to an alternative way of doing this? Either a different way than AVAssetImageGenerator to create a video thumbnail, or some way to create an AVAsset from the data in the filewrapper?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out there's no way to do this, other than saving the file somewhere new and then generating the thumbnail from that.

So what I did instead is that when I add the videos to my package I create the thumbnail then based on the location that I added the file from (I copy the files into my own custom packages).